# How To Set Own Default Date In Material-Datetime-Picker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Here i am using **Material-datetime-picker**. but i need only Date for DOB(Date Of Birth). therefore on initial time Default Date should be from 1990
What Changing Should i Apply In **material-datetime-picker.js**

**index.php**

```
var picker = new MaterialDatetimePicker({})

  .on('submit', function(d) {
    var dt = d.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    $("#dob").val(dt);
  });

$('#dob').click(function () {

picker.open();

});
```

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far for this.

Comment: Code is lengthy how can i upload it.

Comment: Just the portion where you called/initialized the code for the datepicker

Comment: i meant that when user click on picker the date should be show from 1990..i wana use it for DOB

Comment: here is i uploaded code [Click Me](http://textuploader.com/dre3x)

Comment: and this is script which returning date and time
<script>

    var picker = new MaterialDatetimePicker({})
      .on('submit', function(d) {
        
        $("#output").val(d);
      });

    var el = document.querySelector('.c-datepicker-btn');
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      picker.open();
    }, false);

</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace Code in **material-datetime-picker.js**

```
if (!this.value) {
    // TODO hack
    // set/setDate/setTime need refactoring to have single concerns
    // (set: set the value; setDate/setTime rename to renderDate/renderTime
    //  and deal with updating the view only).
    // For now this allows us to set the default time using the same quantize
    // rules as setting the date explicitly. Setting this.value meets setTime|Date's
    // expectation that we have a value, and `0` guarantees that we will detect
    this.value = moment(0);
    this.setDate(this.options.default);
    this.setTime(this.options.default);
  } else {
    this.setDate(this.value);
    this.setTime(this.value);
  }
```

**To**

```
if (!this.value) {
    // TODO hack
    // set/setDate/setTime need refactoring to have single concerns
    // (set: set the value; setDate/setTime rename to renderDate/renderTime
    //  and deal with updating the view only).
    // For now this allows us to set the default time using the same quantize
    // rules as setting the date explicitly. Setting this.value meets setTime|Date's
    // expectation that we have a value, and `0` guarantees that we will detect
    this.value = moment(0);
    this.setDate("12/12/1992");
    this.setTime(this.options.default);
  } else {
    this.setDate(this.value);
    this.setTime(this.value);
  }
```